# Nifty live web tracking

Tags: iis, logging

I'm looking for a real time web log watcher that can visually display visitors as they browse around different pages etc. I'd like it to be a web application, it's going to be shown on a big screen in the office. Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

Check out glTail.rb

http://www.fudgie.org/ The site includes a video of it in operation too.

This is a great looking app that I would highly recommenced the link includes a video of it in action it really is a great thing to have on a big screen.

Not web based but I think you'll agree its cool none the less.

Answer (score 2):

You could write one yourself - just track visitors using a serverside database insert, then periodically refresh your info using ajax.

A simple version of this could be written in very short amount of time.

Answer (score 2):

There is a CMS called EPiServer that has a very nice application called EPiTrace (http://r.ep.se/projects/EPiTrace/) which has a similar approach to what I want. This application is open source, but requires you to have a license for the CMS to run it. I was hoping there was some commerical or open source application with a similar approach. The marketing people (who are going to have this on their screen) isn't very interesting in low-level numbers and protocols. They want to see who's browsing the site, where they are, where they go, etc. And they want to see it in real time in a "easy to understand"-way.

Answer (score 0):

Never tried other ones, but I was amazed when I saw my site in [Woopra](http://www.woopra.com/) for the first time. You don't just see your users as they browse the site (Where they are, for how long, where did they come from etc.), but you can even talk to them if you want (through a chat client that will pop up directly on the site just for the user you want to talk to -- never tried this option for obvious reasons :D) The only con right now is that you have to wait for a while to get your site approved (the app is still in beta; or at least it was when I registered my site). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

this is the easiest and quickest tool for web tracking live...
http://www.realtimevisits.com

no fancy stats very simple and effective.

Answer (score -1):

[Reinvigorate](http://www.reinvigorate.net/) is a cool one. Not a web based app though. You include a js on the file you want monitored and that is reported to their servers, Then you can download an app that shows every visit.